# Javascript regex match text and whitespace or newline

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I need to replace in a document. The tricky part is that the text must match but the spaces can be new lines. So I have
`var myString = 'a b c'`
and need to match instances like `'a b c'` and `'a\nb c'`.

I think `/a\sb\sc/` is the expression I want, but am not sure how to turn the original string into that expression.

I've tried `RegExp(myString.replace(/ /g, '\s'))` which gives me `/asbsc/`.

Please show me how I can turn the given string into the correct regular expression.

Comment: Use `'\\s'`....

Comment: since the backslash is the escape character in a string (to escape the quote), to figure it you need to escape it with an other backslash.

Comment: I would think just hand typing `\\s` where space is should be sufficient. why the need to run a regex on that regex to do that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that works. Probably a dumb question but why does ```myString.replace(/ /g, '\\s')``` return ```'a\\sb\\sc'```? I had actually tried that but thought the double slashes in the output looked wrong.

Comment: They are not doubled, it is only  how the *literal strings* are "coded" as *string literals*.